# virtualenv doesn't activate after system 'macOS Sierra' restart or work folder deactivate

Tags: python, bash, macos, pip, virtualenv

I have problem with virtualenv when working in macOS Sierra, it affect only one of the work folders, that make it very weird for me to get why is happening, when setup the new virtualenv I'm designating folder for it and install it there, after activating it all is working fine till I deactivate the virtualenv or restart the system, than I'm getting this:

```
~/Development/DjangoDEV/FlowersVibeShoppe/venv-flowersvibe-oscar on master
$ source bin/activate
-bash: bin/activate: No such file or directory
```

If I try to list the existing virutalenv it showing it there:

```
~/Development/DjangoDEV/FlowersVibeShoppe/venv-flowersvibe-oscar on master▲
$ lsvirtualenv
venv-flowersvibe-oscar
```

The virtualenv is there, however don't want to activate, I did uninstalled and setup again from scratch like 4 times the result is always the same for this folder, and this affect only one of the work folders the rest of my virtualenv are working fine. Can some one HELP?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`lsvirtualenv` is a command from virtualenv-wrapper, not from virtualenv itself. That project has a separate command for activating virtualenvs: `workon`. So you should do:

```
workon venv-flowersvibe-oscar
```